# How to troubleshoot Microsoft Graph authentication?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How do I go about troubleshooting login problem with the Microsoft Graph API?

I'm using the new nodejs-connect-rest-sample on node 6.9.1, and used the [quick-start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph/quick-start) page to generate and an AppID.   After pressing the "Connect to Microsoft Graph" button, and choosing my normal Hotmail account for login, I'm redirected to an error page saying:

> > **We're unable to complete your request**
> >
> > **Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.**

What's the next step in troubleshooting this sort of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error page URL actually contains a query string with a more detailed explanation than the displayed web page does...   In my case:  [`https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.&state=a9SlXZGisoIQrPQUbDHX732izad7LJzM`](https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20'redirect_uri'%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.&state=a9SlXZGisoIQrPQUbDHX732izad7LJzM)

The login.live.com page *should* be able to display this more detail description, but currently fails to, but I'm going to mark this answered as far as a "next step", because I found I could correct the problem by changing the redirect URL registered for the app.

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the exact same issue -- what ended up being the correct redirect URL?

Comment: Nevermind -- I solved it by changing the redirect URL in the app management area from `http://localhost:3000/login` to `http://localhost:3000/token`.